# When would you use prompting vs. fine tuning?

Tags: open-ai, training-datasets, fine-tuning, prompt

I would like to hear your thoughts on when is it appropriate to use prompting vs. fine-tuning.

Does one make more sense for specific tasks than the other.

Kindly elaborate.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "prompting"? Do you mean what people like to call "prompt engineering", i.e. writing inputs to the model with the hope that the model will return what you want?